# Vertical scrollview with three screen-sized views

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, constraints, autolayout

I'm making a vertical scrolling application using a `UIScrollView` and three `UIViews`. Up until now I've manually set the `height` of the three views and `contentsize` of the scrollview using `storyboard` and some simple code. However, the time has come to adapt it to 3.5" screens as well.

I tried using `autolayout` and setting constraints in the storyboard, but this didn't work out too well. I'm getting all these errors/ warnings about `expected height=0 actual height=504` and `scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content`.

This is my setup:

```
UIViewController {
  UIScrollView {
    UIView {content}
    UIView {content}
    UIView {content}
  }
}
```

Basically, this is what I want to achieve: The content inside the views is fixed to certain locations on the UIView they are in. Pretty standard stuff. 
Now, each of the three UIViews are supposed to be the size of the iPhone screen, and located directly below each other. This way one view fills up the screen at a time, and the user can scroll to the next view which locks into position. The UIScrollView's size should be the size of the screen, however, the contentsize height should be the height of the three views put together.

How can I achieve this? I'd prefer using a solution with storyboards, as I'm used to laying out the app there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Images:**

[image: Layout]
[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

The expected height = 0 comes when the autolayout miscalculates the constraints. You can always update the constraints such that it will take your set value.
Also for a vertical scroll to perform it's action the content size has to be changed in the code.
Instead of setting 
 self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height*5);
in the -(void)viewDidLoad try to set it in -(void)viewDidAppear